# Is there a way to get handle of Datawindow control through Win32 API in PowerBuilder?

Tags: winapi, controls, handle, powerbuilder

I want use Multiline Edit control inside my datawindow control. Is there a way to get handle of the multiline edit control in a window through Win32 API?

There are few different ideas in my mind to play with PowerBuilder controls. If i can get handle of the control or access to any control in a window with win32 API, i think i can change default events behavior or whatever possible to make my life a bit easier with PowerBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Handle(this) or Handle ([object name]) on whatever control you are coding?  Take a look in the PowerBuilder help for the 'Handle PowerScript function'.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Win32 API SetParent function was called and one button that was on window after SetParent was moved to datawindow control. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: of course the dataobject property was already set before the call to SetParent.

Comment: There was no need to get handle of the parent and child controls through Win32 API calls (in my sample application datawindow control was supposed to be a parent control and a button on window was expected child ) . Simple Handle() function of PowerBuilder returns the exact handle needed. the handle() function saved a lot of time.

Comment: The next step is redirection of events. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156116/how-to-re-direct-events-from-one-control-to-another-control-in-powerbuilder

Answer (score 0):

A regular edit column in the DataWindow can act just like a MLE, just play around with the properties. You are overcomplicating things.

Comment: Yes, in parent object there was send function call for enter key to simulate tab key. :) ... but i am still thinking about event redirection because there is way to do it and experienced developer like you with little effort can covert that c# code into PowerBuilder code. The link http://bitmatic.com/c/redirecting-mousewheel-events-to-another-controlabove Please see that link.