# How to re-direct events from one control to another control in PowerBuilder?

Tags: redirect, winapi, events, powerbuilder

A button control can trigger event of a datawindow control with TriggerEvent() function.

The button control in my code was set as child object of DataWindow control with SetParent win32 API function. SetParent external function moves button from window to datawindow control but after SetParent the code that was already written for Clicked event is not working anymore. That is why i need to redirect the clicked event of button to buttonclicked event of datawindow.

There is good example of redirecting event by using win32 API calls. here is the link http://bitmatic.com/c/redirecting-mousewheel-events-to-another-control i need to do the same thing in PowerBuilder.

Can someone see that code or help me to redirect events the way i want?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing things the hard way.  Find the name of the datawindow control (e.g. dw_1), and from the command button just issue dw_1.event buttonclicked ( args ).

Better yet, move the code to a function in the parent object.  Controls are navigation objects, they really shouldn't have too much code in them (IMHO), but fire off methods on the parent object.

Comment: Yes, that is easy way to handle events. Actually the 'hard way' idea started when i needed to have a field in a datawindow for multiple lines of text. RichText can be used but it will not save just the text i need. My objective is to find the way to redirect events because i believe win32 API if used in PowerBuilder i can do many things that are not possible otherwise.

Comment: My main objective behind redirection of events is to give my PowerBuilder app the look of the operating system it runs on. I mean if my app runs on windows 7 then its look should change to windows 7 like GUI. and if my app run on windows 8 then my App should look like the interface windows 8 have. Nevertheless it is very interesting for me to learn how my PowerBuilder app can go out of every limit to do anything that is possible in a .NET framework..

Comment: As you can see if events, functions and properties are handled with win32 API then there is no limit to what you can do in PowerBuilder. I know PowerBuilder is not the best tool for development but at least there is way to do things in a different way. Please see how events can be redirected in PowerBuilder.

Comment: The problem you're going to find you're going to have with PowerBuilder is that the DataWindow is only rendered as two UI controls:  a bitmap that represents what the DataWindow looks like and an edit control that floats above the bitmap for the column that currently has focus.  You're not going to be able to modify the look of the DataWindow through the Windows API.  And given how much a DataWIndow is used in a normal PowerBuilder application, that means most of the app won't be modifiable that way.

Comment: Yes, exactly the look was not the way i wanted. The button that SetParent made child of datawindow was not placed at the location i wanted, certainly there will be need for more external calls. SetParent made it child object but the parent datawindow has no clue if that child exist or not. And if the button does not show itself for each and every row then the button is almost useless.Regardless of every unexpected behavior of the SetParent function for PowerBuilder objects, i think knowledge of redirecting events will generate many options. Please try that. I believe you can do it. Thank you.